# echo pwd remotely via ssh

Tags: ssh, pwd

I need a **remote** machine to print the absolute **path** of a given file hosted on it, so I do:

```
ssh me@remote.host.net "echo '$(pwd)/file.txt'"
```

Too bad this way `pwd` gets evaluated **locally**, not remotely. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip the quotes:

```
ssh me@remote.host.net 'echo "$(pwd)/file.txt"'
```